# ElasticSearch 8 : mapping template not applied to indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

I create an index template affecting all indices matching "shoppers-*" but then, when creating an index of this name format, the template is not applied, the mapping is not retrieved.

1. create template

```
PUT /_index_template/my-template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "shoppers-*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "shopper": {
          "properties": {
            "tag": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": {
      "my-template-alias": {}
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

2. then create an index

```
PUT /shoppers-0001
```

```
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "shards_acknowledged": true,
  "index": "shoppers-0001"
}
```

3. refresh

```
POST /shoppers-0001/_refresh
```

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

4. retrieve mapping on the newly created index

```
GET /shoppers-0001/_mapping
```

```
{
  "shoppers-0001": {
    "mappings": {}
  }
}
```

I cannot figure what could prevent the template to be applied to this index...
Any things I may check to help debug this?

Comment: Can you provide what you get from `GET _cat/templates?v` and `GET _template`?

Comment: Val : thank you for your answer, I realised while sleeping that it could be another template having precedence over mine (see my answer) and your comment would also have led me to realise it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Writing the problem after so many hours looking for an answer took me to the solution !
I am answering my own question for those who are going to read this question later with the same problem.

There were another template matching pattern `*` and having precedence over my template !